# How to edit URL using Node's new URL constructor?

Tags: node.js, url

I'm using a new version of Node.js that has a new way to parse URLs. Rather than `url.parse` you call [`new URL()`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_constructor_new_url_input_base).

The one issue I am having is how to parse and update/manipulate the URL.

For instance with the old `url.parse` I could do this:

```
const p = url.parse('http://example.com')
const edits = {...p, protocol: 'https'}
const np = url.format(edits)
```

This is an example where I'm changing the schema of a URL.

This would be done using the new API as follows:

```
const p = new URL('http://example.com')
```

However this trick doesn't seem to be possible with the new URL, which returns a SYMBOL, so spreading the new value of `p` doesn't work. To make matters worse, some of the properties of `p` are readonly, which is interesting, and means I can't assign the value directly.

There is a `.toJSON()` method in the instance, which ironically doesn't provide JSON values of the parsed URL, but a string version of the assembled URL.

I am curious how to edit and reassemble a URL with the new Node URL API.

Comment: `const p = new URL("http://example.com"); p.protocol = "https"; console.log(p.toString());` seems to work as expected. As for `toJSON`, [*"in practice it seems to have the same effect as `URL.toString()`"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/toJSON)

Comment: @jonrsharpe `searchParams` is one of the readonly properties which uses `URLSearchParams`, how would that be updated?

Comment: With e.g. [`p.searchParams.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set).

Answer (score 2):

I was surprised to find out not all the properties are readonly, and the `searchParams` parameter has a setter.

```
const host = 'https://connect.stripe.com'
const clientId = config.get('STRIPE_CLIENT_ID')
const parsedUrl = new URL('/oauth/authorize', host)
parsedUrl.searchParams.set('scope', 'read_write')
parsedUrl.searchParams.set('client_id', clientId)
parsedUrl.searchParams.set('response_type', 'code')
console.log(parsedUrl.toString())
```

Comment: I'd recommend e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL, which tells you which properties are read only and what types they are, for minimum surprise. The docs you were looking at also link to https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api, which is maybe a little less clearly laid out but does include e.g. *"Gets the `URLSearchParams` object representing the query parameters of the URL. This property is read-only; to replace the entirety of query parameters of the URL, use the `url.search` setter. See `URLSearchParams` documentation for details."*